# How to architect push notifications in a Unity app that is using a PHP back-end for in-app notifications?

Tags: unity, android, ios

I'm working on a mobile game for a client. The tech stack is following:

- Unity for iOS / Android app
- Unity Cloud for building the apps
- Firebase for event analytics
- PHP/Symfony + PostgreSQL for back-end
- REST API for communication between the app and the back-end

The game already implements in-app notifications using the API. On the server, there's a CRON job with business logic that checks for events that should trigger notifications. The logged-in player then fetches a notification end-point to display unread notifications to the player.

The client now wishes for these notifications to also be push notifications for the players, even if they closed the game. What's the best solution for architecting this requirement, considering the tech stack and already existing in-app notification system?
I already considered the following:

- [Set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging client app with Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client)

  - I'm not sure how to do the extra configuration for both Android and iOS using the Cloud Build
  - I'm not sure what I need to do on my server to trigger those messages
- [One Signal](https://onesignal.com/)

  - similar concerns as above, plus I'm not sure if the extra cost is worth it?

Comment: Keep in mind that "which technology to use" questions are not on-topic on this exchange, so to avoid close votes I'd recommend editing the question to make it clear that you're not asking for library/middleware recommendations.

Comment: Thank you @DMGregory, I edited my question, hope it's clearer now.